# DNS Look up failed - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, dns

I have this problem, which seems to be a 'common' problem on Ubuntu.
When I try to open some pages on chromium I get the "DNS look up failed" error. (It doesn't say exactly that on Firefox but it's the same problem).

The thing is I've tried every of the answers I've found on that issue and none of the have gotten permanently rid of the problem.

I've renamed the **resolv.conf** file:

```
    cd /etc
    sudo mv resolv.conf backup.resolv.conf
```

No luck.

I've also commented out the *dnsmasq* from the **NetworkManager.conf** file with

```
    sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

by putting a "#". It ended up:

```
    [main]
    plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
    #dns=dnsmasq

    [ifupdown]
    managed=false
```

Then I restarted the *network-manager* service

```
    sudo restart network-manager
```

It worked once really nice. But next time I turned on the computer it was just the same and from there on there was nothing I could do. 
It's so incredibly infuriating.

I'm in love with Ubuntu, but that one problem is such a deal-breaker. I couldn't even ask this question from Ubuntu. I need some help, please.

EDIT:

Output from `nm-tool`:

> NetworkManager Tool
>
> State: connected (global)
>
> - Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
>     Type:              Wired
>     Driver:            sky2
>     State:             unavailable
>     Default:           no
>     HW Address:        00:23:AE:35:96:8D
>
>   Capabilities:
>     Carrier Detect:  yes
>
>   Wired Properties
>     Carrier:         off
> - Device: eth1  [GRojas Home] --------------------------------------------------
>     Type:              802.11 WiFi
>     Driver:            wl
>     State:             connected
>     Default:           yes
>     HW Address:        70:1A:04:71:03:D0
>
>   Capabilities:
>     Speed:           54 Mb/s
>
>   Wireless Properties
>     WEP Encryption:  yes
>     WPA Encryption:  yes
>     WPA2 Encryption: yes
>
>   Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
>     Flia. Castillo:  Infra, 88:53:D4:D8:C9:70, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 >WPA WPA2
>     CLARO334:        Infra, EC:43:F6:BB:2F:FC, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 22 >WPA2
>     *GRojas Home:    Infra, 00:25:86:B1:7D:62, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 92 >WPA
>
>   IPv4 Settings:
>     Address:         192.168.1.100
>     Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
>     Gateway:         192.168.1.1
>
>   DNS:             192.168.100.1
>     DNS:             192.168.1.1

Comment: can you give output from command `nm-tool`?

Comment: Yes, of course. There it is.

Comment: Can you give more information about your network?  Your setup implies you have two separate DNS servers on separate private networks available locally.  Do you know which DNS servers your system should be using?  Do these DNS servers work?  You can test a DNS server with, for example, `dig @192.168.100.1 google.com` where 192.168.100.1 is the first DNS server in use for your GRojas wifi adapter.  Or you can test your system's default DNS with something like `dig google.com`.

Also just curious, was the reason you disabled dnsmasq?

Comment: Based on output you can not resolve logical name to ip address. Try to put for dns servers, dns servers of yours ISP or you can put google dns 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. You can put it on router if your pc got address via dhcp, or you can put it manuali on settings of your connection.